# How to install and run a precompiled package on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, qt

I am trying to install and run terracoin wallet on my ubuntu 16.04. The downloaded package comes with `lib` ,`bin` and `include`folders. Inside the `bin`, there is `terracoin-qt` file that is supposed to launch the wallet but typing it on the terminal gives `terracoin-qt: command not found` I am still new to linux but I am hoping I could conveniently install and run without getting confused with technical steps.

Comment: Cd to the bin directory, and run `./terracoin-qt` ...

Answer (score 0):

Is it an executable file?If so then run the command like `./terracoin-qt`
If it says no permission then try to run chmod a+x

Answer (score 0):

If you call `bin/terracoin-qt` from Wallet Application in the Main Page of Terracoin Websites. that's would show log "segmentation fault (core dumped)", cause you didn't have required dependency package for that.

**The Required Dependencies Build Package :**

1. Libssl for Crypto of the Random Number Generation, Elliptic Curve Cryptography..
2. Libboost for Utility of the Library for threading, data structures, etc.
3. Libevent for Networking of the OS independent asynchronous networking.

To Build Requirements run using :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool autotools-dev automake pkg-config libssl-dev libevent-dev bsdmainutils
```

For the individual boost development packages, run using :

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-chrono-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-thread-dev
```

and you also need required package for Wallet, BerkeleyDB is required. you can add the repository and install using :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++-dev
```

**The Required Dependencies for the Terracoin GUI :**

**Make sure** that the required packages for Qt development are installed.
To build the QT5 you need to following

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
```

After all Dependencies had been required, Build that's with Source Codes.

**Builds with Source Codes :**
to Builds that, get the Source Code from [Terracoin_Github].[1](https://github.com/terracoin/terracoin.git)

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/terracoin/terracoin.git
cd terracoin
TERRACOIN_ROOT=$(pwd)
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

Wait a minutes after that's be done, so you can Build BerkeleyDB using :

```
BDB_PREFIX="${TERRACOIN_ROOT}/db4"
mkdir -p $BDB_PREFIX
cd $BDB_PREFIX
wget 'http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-4.8.30.NC.tar.gz'
echo '12edc0df75bf9abd7f82f821795bcee50f42cb2e5f76a6a281b85732798364ef  db-4.8.30.NC.tar.gz' | sha256sum -c
tar -xzvf db-4.8.30.NC.tar.gz
```

then Build the library and install to your prefix.

```
cd db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix/
../dist/configure --enable-cxx --disable-shared --with-pic --prefix=$BDB_PREFIX
make install
```

and configure the Terracoin again to use your build instance of BDB.

```
cd $TERRACOIN_ROOT
./autogen.sh
./configure LDFLAGS="-L${BDB_PREFIX}/lib/" CPPFLAGS="-I${BDB_PREFIX}/include/"
```

You didn't need moving all binary Terracoin to your `/usr/local/bin`, cause that's builds automatically stored all binary and libraries. you just need configuration service and init scripts like sample scripts in `contrib/init/`.

**To installing Service Configuration :**

**For Systemd Configuration**, just copying `.service` in sample scripts to `/usr/lib/systemd/system` directory, and run `systemctl daemon-reload` to update systemd configuration, and start service with `systemctl start terracoind`.

**For OpenRC Configuration**, just rename `.openrc` in sample scripts to `/etc/init.d`, using command `mv terracoind.openrc /etc/init.d/terracoind`, and run using `/etc/init.d/terracoind start`.

**For UpStart Configuration**, just copying `terracoind.conf` in sample scripts to `/etc/init`, and test run with `service terracoind start`.

After all Builds and all Configuration did done.
Try run Terracoin Core using,

```
terracoin-qt
```

if running, it will appear like this

[image: Terracoin_Core_GUI]

else if run, Congratulation Sir.

Comment: This worked now but closes abruptly with the info "segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: @rexdavinci please edit your question with links about your package, steps your installation and output error log sir

Comment: I had to do was follow your answer and it worked but it crashes as soon as it opens with "Segmentation fault (core dumped). But after I notified the developers, I was instructed to correct it by moving bin/* into /usr/local/bin. So I could launch it from the terminal using "terracoin-qt". As for the error, I launched it once using "terracoin-qt -rescan" to stop that from happening again. Thanks.

Comment: moving terracoin bin in /usr/local/bin that's mean as globally bin, and have you installed the QT package sir? cause terrracoin-qt needs QT gui package for that like QT5 or QT4.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am a newbie to ubuntu but I believe QT was installed during the installation phase of the OS.

Comment: emm on your init scripts, what that said in Service file: terracoind.service and Configuration file: /etc/terracoincore/terracoin.conf sir?

Comment: Both scripts are blank. Copying the bin/* into /usr/local/bin/ worked the magic.

Comment: For an example configuration file that describes the configuration settings, please see contrib/debian/examples/terracoin.conf sir

Comment: Please check my Update Answered sir.